# Fetch array and element in same line

Tags: php, arrays

I used this on my local server (XAMPP, latest version):

```
$num_entries = intval( mysqli_fetch_array( $result )[0] );
```

which worked fine but after deployment my host's PHP is saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/aaa/public_html/php/Database.php on line 38
```

I'm guessing this must be due to some retro-compatability issue.

My host is running PHP 5.3.28.

So what's the most efficient way of fetching an array and getting the first element in a single statement?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in one line.

Comment: Do you need an array? `mysqli_fetch_object($result)->{0}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  De-referencing the return of a function as an array was added in 5.4.0.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );
$num_entries = intval( $row[0] );
```

Comment: But my query is `SELECT COUNT(*)` so there is only one row?

Answer (score 4):

That syntax is not legal in PHP 5.3, but it is in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) which introduced support for function array dereferencing.

The only option in 5.3 and below is to do it in 2 lines vs one.

```
$num_entries = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );
$num_entries = intval($num_entries[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempted answer but I did mention that in my question. I'm asking for an efficient way of doing it, not why it isn't working! :) Ok for two lines then!